# In-quadword-vector Shuffle with ARM NEON

Tags: arm, intrinsics, neon

I want to switch the two elements stored in a 128-bit (quadword) NEON register.

```
[a3, a2, a1, a0] --> [a3, a1, a2, a0]
```

After reading GNU's "ARM NEON Intrinsics" and ARM ACLE, it seems it can done as:

```
// qr0 being the input vector variable of type float32x4_t
float32x2_t hi = vget_high_f32(qr0);
float32x2_t lo = vget_low_f32(qr0);
float32x2x2_t qr0_z = vzip_f32(hi, lo); //may also use transpose
qr0 = vcombine_f32(qr0_z.val[0], qr0_z.val[1]);
```

My question is: is this any better way to do this via intrinsics? Thank you for reading this.

Comment: I'm also a little iffy with `float32x2x2_t` in general. It doesn't seem to always align the two d-word registers to the same q-word register.

Comment: @user3528438, thank you. I think the table lookup `VTBL` is more of a general _blend_ instruction.

Comment: Define "better" - This compiles to a single `vtrn.32` plus some register moves to swap the two halves of `qr0` first (which seems wrong - are you sure you didn't mean `vzip_f32(lo, hi)`?), which is essentially optimal. What are you after on top of that?

Comment: Your solution is of the best ways to do what you want.  It only looks long-winded because of the less-than-ideal syntax that intrinsics offer to get this done.

Comment: @Notlikethat, I may be wrong with param order in `uzip_f32()`. I'm just cross-compiling and checking the generated assemblies. What's your take on the use of `float32x2x2_t`? Is there a way I can force the Tx2 to be aligned to one quadword register?

Comment: @sh1, Thank you! What's your take on the use of `float32x2x2_t`? It serves as the output type of quite a few memory ops. I'm very iffy about `vcombine_f32` generating additional ops when the `float32x2x2_t` is in fact crossing two quadword register. Is there a way I can force the Tx2 to be aligned to one quadword register?

Comment: _"Is there a way I can force the Tx2 to be aligned to one quadword register?"_ - effectively, yes, and you're already doing it: `qr0 = vcombine_f32(qr0_z.val[0], qr0_z.val[1])` - no sensible compiler will emit moves if it can allocate the right registers to begin with, so `qr0_z` never actually exists; it's all just syntax to keep the C type system happy. And if `hi` and `lo` are flipped, the entire thing (as a standalone function) compiles to the expected `vtrn.32 d0, d1; bx lr`; I don't understand where this problem you perceive comes from.

Comment: @Notlikethat, thank you for your explanation. I agree that the compiler should be able to figure out how to optimize this. The reason I'm (irrationally) iffy is that I know pretty well how compilers optimize X86 intrinsics, but I'm fiarly new to NEON intrinsics, and maybe I have a pessimistic character in general.

Comment: Note also that your concern is misplaced anyway. A `float32x2x2_t` represents two D registers, nothing more - the compiler is free to put one into `d17` and `d3` if it wants to. The only thing which needs aligning to a Q register is the `float32x4_t`, and you can be damn sure the compiler will do that correctly, even if it _did_ actually allocate any storage for the intermediate variable. If you want a laugh, compile at -O0 and note that, despite being utterly ridiculous (in the case of GCC, at least), the emitted code and register allocations are still nevertheless _correct_.

Comment: @Notlikethat Thank you. My main concern of `float32x2x2_t` vs `float32x4_t` is the performance implication. If, say, `float32x2x2_t` is placed in `d17` and `d3`, is the arithmetic operations on this `float32x2x2_t` slower than a `float32x4_t`?

Comment: Tell me which arithmetic operations take a `float32x2x2_t` as an _input_...